# Is atime/mtime updated on fopen, fread/fwrite and/or fclose?

Tags: linux, filesystems

I'm just curious; Is atime updated on `fread`, `fopen` and/or `fclose`?

What about mtime? Is it updated on `fopen`, `fwrite` and/or `fclose`?

Comment: Why don't you just try it? Considering that the test program for each case is about 4 lines long, I think your time would have been better spent doing that than writing this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your `strace` your process, you'll see the `fopen` and corresponding system `stat`. To use `PHP` as an example.

**Example with PHP**

First make sure the file system is updating these values,

```
    mount -o remount,atime,diratime /
```

Then make a small script.

```
    <?php
      echo "fopen: " .date("H:i:s \n");
      $fh = fopen('test.tmp', 'r');
      sleep(2);
      echo "fread: ".date("H:i:s \n");
      fread($fh,1024);
      sleep(2);
      echo "fwrite: ".date("H:i:s \n");
      fwrite($fh,'test');
      sleep(2);
      echo "fclose: ".date("H:i:s \n");
      fclose($fh);
      echo shell_exec('stat test.tmp');
```

Then make the test case and execute

```
    echo test > test.tmp
    php test.php
```

Which results in ...

```
    [/]$ php test.php
    fopen: 14:31:34
    fread: 14:31:36
    fwrite: 14:31:38
    fclose: 14:31:40
      File: `test.tmp'
      Size: 5               Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
    Device: 805h/2053d      Inode: 98213       Links: 1
    Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
    Access: 2012-09-27 14:31:36.000000000 +0100
    Modify: 2012-09-27 14:28:28.000000000 +0100
    Change: 2012-09-27 14:28:28.000000000 +0100
```

So ...

1. `fread` should correlate with `atime`
2. `fwrite` should correlate with `mtime`.

**Reference**

```
    mtime: time of last modification    (eg. ls -l)
    ctime: time of last status change   (eg. ls -lc)
    atime: time of last access          (eg. ls -lu)
```

This is pretty well documented as part of the `stat` function, ref. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stat_%28system_call%29

Answer (score -2):

You have to open the file with `'w'` for write to work:

```
$fh = fopen('test.tmp', 'w');
```